# Homebrew installing in wrong location?

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm currently beginning to learn ruby and have been running through a tutorial at [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ruby-on-rails-intro/lecture/mXAJX/software-installation-for-mac-users). In the tutorial I get stuck really early on during install homebrew...

The lecturer does an **ls -al** call in terminal that shows '**homebrew**' in the list but when I do it, it doesn't come up.

I'm finding my homebrew in usr/local/library/homebrew but I cant seem to cd into there to keep on following the tutorial.

When I try to cd homebrew/ I get this message - **-bash: cd: homebrew: No such file or directory**

I feel like I've screwed up at some point early on but I can't find it. I've tried to uninstall script and repeating but I'm getting the same results...

Maybe I'm just being stupid but it's stopping me continuing as I can't write directly into the folder.

Can someone tell me how I'm screwing up?

Comment: Stop the video at 4:22 and look at the first comand. Double check if you used the same one. It starts with `mkdir homebrew && ...`

Comment: Dude, I love you. Thanks! I'm not sure at what point I screwed that up but it's now in users:) Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -1):

The lecturer thinks what you in the directory where homebrew is installing, but you not.

To find where is your homebrew use:

```
$ brew --prefix
```

Comment: This is what I'm getting when I do this 

-bash: $: command not found